# Two Domain Controller in Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to setup two Domain Controller in my domain. The reasson is that it provide me fault tolerance, if one Domain Controller is down the other is ready to proccess request.

I only have 2 windows server (2 domain controler) no more windows servers. If I only had one Domain Controller when I configure the client to login with domain user I must specify a DNS server (would be Domain Controller) in interface options (on clients). But in this case I have 2 Domain Controller, how can I tell clients where is the domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the DNS server is one of your domain controllers, it will all work out.

AD publishes `SRV` records, which clients use to locate the domain controllers.

Comment: Yes, but whats happen If that Domain Controller (DNS server also) is down? there isn't fault tolerance, the client won't find Domain Controller

Comment: Yes, they will find the domain controller. Honestly, though, keep your DCs up. Having them down should be *very* rare. You've been operating on a single DC for some time now, by adding a second, you're drastically improving your availability.

Comment: So, in my clients I only need specify one Domain Controller as DNS server? they still working when one Domain controller is offline?

Comment: No, install the DNS role in all of your DCs, and specify all of those addresses as DNS servers in your clients.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the DNS Server Role is installed on the new Domain Controller.
2. Make sure that your AD DNS zones are Active Directory integrated so that they replicate between the two Domain controllers.
3. Configure your domain clients to use both DC\ DNS servers for DNS.

Comment: I understand Step 1 and 2 but in the third step.. I only can specify one Main DNS Server and one Secondary DNS Server, if I had 3 Domain Controller I can't put it as DNS server as long as only can put 2 DNS server (one as main and one as secondary)

Comment: Honestly, you're a bit out of your depth. If you have two DC\DNS servers then you configure your DNS client settings to use one DC\DNS server as primary and the other DC\DNS server as secondary. If you had a third DC\DNS server (or a fourth or a fifth, etc.) you could add those on the DNS tab of the Advanced TCP/IP Settings pages of the TCP/IPv4 protocol on your clients.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that and I was going to do it in this way but I had read in a microsoft forum that do that doesn't correct.

Comment: @RdlP Actually, you can specify a lot more than 2 DNS servers, you just can't use the GUI to do it.  All the domain controllers in my employer's production domain have ~20 DNS servers specified, for example (every other domain controller in the forest).

Comment: You can add as many as you want from the DNS tab of the Advanced TCP/IP Settings pages of the TCP/IPv4 protocol on the clients.